# Why do I get this on my renders?

Tags: rendering

I’ve recently started learning blender so I know very little about it although I feel I’m making steady progress.
I’ve just been messing around a bit with things I’ve learnt but a few times now I’ve had the render result come out like the attached photo and I’m not sure why?
I’ve rendered it in Eevee, with render on 209 and viewport on 16.
Sometimes the render has come out purple?
Many thanks for reading and your help in advance and apologies if this seems like a stupid nooby question. [image]

Comment: Can you please upload your .blend file so others can try to reproduce the issue you're experiencing?

Comment: Since I was just messing about making stuff I didn’t save this file but just wanted to know for future reference.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the problem and then save a blend file? This will drastically help in regards to finding an answer to your issue.

Comment: I've reproduced, i just dont know how to upload the file here?

Comment: Go here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Upload your file, check the agreement boxes, and paste the URL of this question into the box provided. After hitting upload, you will be given a link. Edit your own question, and paste that link into the question body.

Comment: That could be a bug with GPU rendering the wrong value for the alpha channel. I doubt it has anything to do with the file itself. What GPU are you using? Try modifying the tile size. Does the rendered image look OK if you view just the RGB values (with no alpha)?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=7G5Salo7" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/7G5Salo7/)

Comment: Hello and welcome.Please use a descriptive title on your posts. Also see [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: The file renders correctly on my system. I'm almost certain this is a hardware (or hardware configuration) issue or bug.